# RavenDB: Attempt to query by id only is blocked. Now Include() doesn't work

Tags: ravendb

For a long time now, this code has been working well for me:

```
session.Query<Application>()
    .Include(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIds)
    .Where(app => app.Id == id).FirstOrDefault())
```

However, I just upgraded my RavenDB assemblies, and I'm now getting this error:

> Attempt to query by id only is blocked, you should use call
>   session.Load("applications/4"); instead of
>   session.Query().Where(x=>x.Id == "applications/4");
>
> You can turn this error off by specifying
>   documentStore.Conventions.AllowQueriesOnId = true;, but that is not
>   recommend and provided for backward compatibility reasons only.

Okay, fine, I changed it to this:

```
session.Load<Application>(id)
    .Include(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIds)
```

But now my Include() method doesn't work:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Include'.

How do I use `Include()` with `session.Load()`?

**Edit:**

I've found the answer (see my answer below). Now I'm trying to find out how this fits into the new `session.Load()` approach:

```
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()
```

Comment: When you Load, it goes directly to the document store, where staleness isn't a concern.  Even on a query, you shouldn't be waiting for nonstale results in a production scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/faq/optimizing-referenced-documents-load). I needed to use `Include()` on the `session`, not on `Load()`.

```
session.Include<Application>(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIds)
    .Load<Application>(id))
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  The include statement comes first on a load.